# Writing code on arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, automata

I am trying to write code on arrows between nodes. Ideally I would like the code to be on the left (or right) of the arrow and in the middle. Is there a way to acheive just that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8 cm, scale = 1, transform shape]

    \node[state](A){$n_0$};
    \node[state](B)[below of=A]{$n_1$};
    \node[state](C)[below left of=B]{$n_2$};
    \node[state](D)[below right of=B]{$n_3$};

    \path[->](A) edge [below] node [align=center] {} (B)
             (B) edge [below] node [align=left] {$\text{\texttt{j < inputExpr.length()}}$} (C)
             (B) edge [below] node [align=left] {$\text{\texttt{j >= inputExpr.length()}}$} (D);

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the distance of the nodes, then apply `sloped` to the nodes so they follow the arrow and a smaller font.

`midway` is equivalent to `pos=0.5`. If you want change what side of the arrow the node is placed, you can add `above` or `below` like this:

```
\node [narrow, above] ...
```

So that above adds to the `narrow` (node arrow) node style defined in the `\tikzset`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\tikzset{
    narrow/.style={sloped, font=\scriptsize, midway}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 1, transform shape]

    \node[state](A){$n_0$};
    \node[state](B)[below of=A]{$n_1$};
    \node[state](C)[below left of=B]{$n_2$};
    \node[state](D)[below right of=B]{$n_3$};

    \path[->](A) edge [below] node [align=center] {} (B)
             (B) edge [below] node [narrow] {$\text{\texttt{j < inputExpr.length()}}$} (C)
             (B) edge [below] node [narrow] {$\text{\texttt{j >= inputExpr.length()}}$} (D);

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```